# Running code dynamically in C#

Tags: c#-4.0

I am working on a game in C#.

I have a list of events, that can happen. E.g

`List<Event> _events = new List<Event>();
 _events.Add(new Event("A goblin approaches", 2));
 _events.Add(new Event("A gang of thieves approaches", 3));
 _events.Add(new Event("Some money has been stolen", 3));
 _events.Add(new Event("Three goblins approach", 4));
 _events.Add(new Event("A guard dies of unknown causes",4));`

The string in the Event constructor is the event name and the number is the difficulty.

I was wondering if I could also add code into the constructor that can be run later on if the event is called. I'd like different code in each event.

Something like

`_events.Add(new Event("Some money has been stolen", 3, "Supply.Gold = Supply.Gold -50"));
_events[2].runcode`

I hope this makes sense, thanks

Comment: Why you can't dispatch fired event and execute your code from dispatcher? Or subclass Event and add virtual DoGood() method which will perform appropriate action?

Comment: @deeptowncitizen how can I pass a function into a constructor?

Comment: You can use delegates. Watch for C# Action

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With this approach you can create events with simple implementation. And also difficult events with a lot of code (by extending Event class).

```
public class EventContext
{
    public int Gold { get; set; }
}

public interface IEvent
{
    void Do(EventContext context);
}

public abstract class Event : IEvent
{
    protected Event(string title, int difficulty)
    {
        Title = title;
        Difficulty = difficulty;
    }

    public string Title { get; private set; }
    public int Difficulty { get; private set; }


    public abstract void Do(EventContext context);
}

public class SimpleEvent : Event
{
    private readonly Action<EventContext> _callback;

    public SimpleEvent(string title, int difficulty, Action<EventContext> callback)
        : base(title, difficulty)
    {
        _callback = callback;
    }

    public override void Do(EventContext context)
    {
        _callback(context);
    }
}

internal class Program
{
    private static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var gameContext = new EventContext {Gold = 100};
        var events = new List<IEvent>();
        events.Add(new SimpleEvent("Some money has been stolen", 3, context => context.Gold -= 10));

        events.First().Do(gameContext);
    }
}
```

But I believe it can be better to separate event type and event handler.

Comment: Thank you for your time and help. I have not used actions before. I will definitely have a read up. Thanks again